# Confusion in service endpoint interface for Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I tried to create a simple web service for checking whether the input number is prime number using JAX-WS by referring to an online tutorial. I used the service first approach and created the web service class first and after generated the WSDL. After I generated the stub using **wsimport** command.

I am having a confusion about Service Endpoint Interface (SEI). What is the service endpoint interface here? Is that the **generated class** using wsimport command with @WebService annotation

```
@WebService(name = "PrimeNumberServiceDeligator", targetNamespace = "http://math.test/")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
public interface PrimeNumberServiceDeligator {
    // .....
}
```

or is Service Endpoint Interface the class we annotate with @WebService and implement by our self without generating using wsimpot command which contains our business logic ?

```
@WebService
public class PrimeNumberServiceImpl implements PrimeNumberService {
    @Override
    public boolean isPrimeNumber(int number) {
        if(number == 1){
                   return false;
                }
        for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
                        if(number == 2){
                           return true;
                        }
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

if this is the **SEI** then what is called as the web service....?

I have a confusing what is the Service Endpoint Interface (SEI)? I am very new to Web services and please anybody help me to clarify this clearly

thanks a lot

Comment: Can anybody answer this question....still I was unable to fix this ....!

Comment: Your question is not very coherent: In the first bit, you're referring to wsimport, a tool for generating web service **clients**, then you talk about implementing a `@WebService` yourself, that is creating a **web service**. Which is you're doing? If you're the client, the interface is defined by whatever you find in `PrimeNumberServiceDeligator `